# handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none password keyboard-interactive], no supported methods remain

Tags: virtualbox, packer, rancher

The problem in this question resembles [SSH failed when building RancherOS with Packer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606092/ssh-failed-when-building-rancheros-with-packer?noredirect=1#comment85259001_38606092)

However, the behavior of my Packer is different. I get

```
==> virtualbox-iso: Error waiting for SSH: ssh: handshake failed: ssh:
unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none password keyboard-
interactive], no supported methods remain
```

I am not sure why Packer is not able to ssh into the VM. I can see VirtualBox Console Screen sits on a login input. Then it timeouts and gets discarded by packer's process.

**packer.json**

```
{
 "variables": {
  "ros_version" : "v1.1.4",
  "iso_md5" : "b1f395a86c7c040702ec77fe87abb2e2",
  "vm_name" : "rancher_image"
  },
  "builders": [
  {
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "iso_url": "https://releases.rancher.com/os/{{ user `ros_version` }}/rancheros.iso",
      "guest_os_type": "Linux_64",
      "guest_additions_mode": "disable",
      "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
      "iso_checksum": "{{ user `iso_md5` }}",
      "output_directory": "output_rancheros",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "120s",
      "shutdown_command": "sudo shutdown -h now",
      "disk_size": 8000,
      "ssh_username": "rancher",
      "ssh_password": "rancher",
      "headless" : false,
      "ssh_port": 22,
      "ssh_host_port_min": 2222,
      "ssh_host_port_max": 4444,
      "ssh_skip_nat_mapping": true,
      "vm_name": "{{ user `vm_name` }}",
      "boot_wait": "30s",
      "vboxmanage":[
        ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory","4096"]
      ]
  }
],
"provisioners": [
  {
      "type":"file",
      "source": "cloud-config.yml",
      "destination": "/tmp/cloud-config.yml"
  },
  {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
          "ifconfig",
          "sudo ros install -d /dev/sda -f -c /tmp/cloud-config.yml -i rancher/os:{{ user `ros_version` }} --no-reboot"
      ]
   }
 ]
}
```

**cloud-config.yml**

```
#cloud-config
rancher:
  ssh_authorized_keys:
    - ssh-rsa AAA ... some VALID RSA email@email.com
  network:
  interfaces:
    eth0:
      dhcp: true
    dns:
      nameservers:
        -8.8.8.8
        -8.8.4.4
```

Edit:
Added these lines in the builder and removed their equivalents from provisioners. This still does not solve the other steps that I want to have, but at least cloud-config is uploaded and configuration can be done.

```
      "http_directory":"http",
      "boot_command":[
          "<esc><esc><enter><wait>",
          "wget http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/cloud-config.yml <enter>",
          "sudo ros install -d /dev/sda -f -c cloud-config.yml -i rancher/os:{{ user `ros_version` }}",
          "<enter>"],
```

Answer (score 1):

RancherOS doesn't have ssh password enabled by default. See [issue #1467](https://github.com/rancher/os/issues/1467)

Comment: Thanks, It's not clear to me how to set the password before ssh happens via packer. cloud-config or provisioners are not executed until after.

Comment: Just put the cloud-config.yml in your http directory and use boot_command to use it for configuration.

Comment: Would you have a link to an example on how to use http server to pull cloud-config.yml? I've done it with Debian installation, but I don't think I can reuse that code. Debian Example: "preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/{{user `preeseed_file`}} <wait>"

Comment: At the end I added http directory and boot command as per your suggestion.

Comment: Rickard, I'd like to accept your answer as the answer, but could you review my solution and improve on it or copy paste it in your answer, please? One-liners are elegant but still more suitable for comments than answers :)

Comment: I'm on my phone so feel free to answer and accept your own answer. Also it would be good to raise an issue with RancherOS to fix the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```sh
{
  "variables": {
    "vcpus": "1",
    "disk_size": "30000",
    "ftp_proxy": "{{ env `ftp_proxy` }}",
    "headless": "false",
    "iso_checksum": "sha256:d70520b1edd51d3f45a407fbffd820ec4b5cc4a6b7a73d822a687facd9c07e92",
    "iso_url": "https://github.com/rancher/os/releases/download/v1.5.6/rancheros.iso",
    "memory": "2048",
    "ssh_password": "rancher",
    "ssh_username": "rancher",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "ENVIRONMENT": "master",
    "vm_name": "{{user `ENVIRONMENT`}}-rancher",
    "format": "ovf",
    "http_server": "http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/",
    "output_path": "output-{{ user `vm_name` }}"
  },
  "builders": [
    {
      "boot_command": [
        "<enter>",
        "wget http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/{{ user `vm_name` }}-cloud-config.yml <enter>",
        "sudo ros install -d /dev/sda -f -c {{ user `vm_name` }}-cloud-config.yml -no-reboot <enter>",
        "<wait15>",
        "sudo shutdown <enter>"
      ],
      "boot_wait": "30s",
      "communicator": "none",
      "cpus": "{{ user `vcpus` }}",
      "disk_size": "{{ user `disk_size` }}",
      "guest_os_type": "Linux_64",
      "headless": "{{ user `headless` }}",
      "http_directory": "http",
      "iso_checksum": "{{ user `iso_checksum` }}",
      "iso_url": "{{ user `iso_url` }}",
      "memory": "{{ user `memory` }}",
      "format": "{{ user `format` }}",
      "output_directory": "{{ user `output_path` }}",
      "disable_shutdown": true,
      "shutdown_timeout": "5m",
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "vm_name": "{{ user `vm_name` }}",
      "guest_additions_mode": "disable",
      "virtualbox_version_file": ""
    }
  ]
}
```